# Creating a line chart with openpyxl - "The reference is not valid"

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a line chart with openpyxl. The two axes should be `time` and `battery voltage`. Creating the chart with openpyxl sets one axis as battery voltage and the other as the row number. Manually selecting the two columns makes the chart correctly. Opening the sheet the charts are created on gives the error: "The reference is not valid. References for titles, values, or sizes must be a single cell, row, column."

I don't understand how a line chart could only use one column or row. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import os
import openpyxl
import re
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time

os.chdir('C:\\Users\user\folder')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
wb.create_sheet('sheet2') # sheet where charts go
ws1 = wb['sheet1']
ws2 = wb['sheet2']

for cell in ws1['B:B']:
    ws2.cell(row = cell.row, column = 1, value = cell.value)
for cell in ws1['D:D']:
    ws2.cell(row = cell.row, column = 2, value = cell.value)

print('Creating charts...')
sheet = wb['sheet2'] # focus on sheet2 to pull data from/write chart to
refObj = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
seriesObj = openpyxl.chart.Series(refObj, title='Battery Voltage')
chartObj = openpyxl.chart.LineChart()
chartObj.title = 'Title'
chartObj.append(seriesObj)
sheet.add_chart(chartObj, 'C5')
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

Here's what openpyxl creates:
[image: Here's what openpyxl creates]

And selecting columns A and B and creating a line chart in Excel makes the chart I'm trying to get:
[image]

Are my arguments for the LineChart object wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
refObj = openpyxl.chart.Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
```

Creates the graph properly, but sets the row number as the x axis. I'm still trying to get the time in the x axis.

Comment: Can you simplify the code to include only the creation of the chart. It looks to me like you are not following the instructions carefully enough but all the regex makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Sure. Apologies for the excess. I felt the regex was necessary because it fixed a time formatting but I encountered in this program earlier. My previous questions always had comments saying I had too little code so I thought I would be more code complete in this one.

Comment: You haven't set the categories for the chart. I suggest you copy the example from the documentation for a small set of the data and base your work on it.

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks for the advice. So far I've been reading https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html for creating a line chart. Is this the correct page you were referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation more closely solved my problem. Here is the code required to make a line chart with a properly formatted date axis (for my application):

```
c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = "Title"
c1.y_axis.crossAx = 500
c1.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
c1.x_axis.number_format = 'd-HH-MM-SS'
c1.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"

c1.y_axis.title = "Voltage"
c1.x_axis.title = "Time"

data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
dates = Reference(ws2, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=sheet.max_row)
c1.set_categories(dates)
```

Comment: Can I know the use of the y_axis.crossAx = 500 property?